# Reading json with c#

Tags: c#, json, object

I get data in json format from a stock exchange site.

The first part of it looks like this:

```
 {
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-06-12 16:00:00",
        "4. Interval": "5min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    }   
}
```

I would like to read it into an object in c#. I have tried different ways to define the object class. But   the format of the json string puzzles me, so I am stuck here. The object class looks like this:

public class MetaData1

```
{
    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public string MetaData { get; set; }

}
```

I know it is not the full description of the class. But I miss understanding of the json string.

Comment: do the attribute-names within the JSON really contain a number in front? This does not seem like valid JSON.

Comment: I highly recommend you to use Json.NET from Newtonsoft (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Install the NuGet package and deserialize in order to a model.

Comment: Try using this site, it will generate c# classes for you: https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp

Comment: Generating classes on this json seems like it would be unreliable unless you always get these 6 items and only these 6 items. You would have to annotate your classes with property names because the json does not follow valid c# identifier naming rules.

Answer (score 0):

In you class you have defined MetaData as a string. But according to the given JSON the property "Meta Data" isn't a simple string. It's a separate object with its own properties and should be represented in its own class.

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData
{
    [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string Information { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. Symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming you use Newtonsoft.JSON, you should then be able to deserialize the JSON like this:

```
var apiResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(json);
```

Comment: Ok, I never thought of a object in another object. I have tried the solution from you and it works. Super.